# sencha touch Cannot read property 'detach' of null comes up that is cause by setActiveItem

Tags: sencha-touch

I am developing app with sencha touch but facing a problem when activating a tab on a tapPanel
I'm making a tab active by next statement:

```
tabpanel.setActiveItem('#idLogin');
```

Everything works fine and the tab is actually activated, but later on (so not directly after this statement) an error appears in the console.log. When removing this piece of code the error doesn't appear so I am sure it is related to this statement. 
The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'detach' of null
```

Does anybody has faced this issue and were you able to solve?

Answer (score 3):

First, define "later on." Run your app using sencha-touch-all-debug.js to locate the statement throwing the error.

Second, look at the source. You'll see that 'detach' is sencha-speak for 'remove an element from the DOM:"

```
 detach: function() {
    var dom = this.dom;

    if (dom && dom.parentNode && dom.tagName !== 'BODY') {
        dom.parentNode.removeChild(dom);
    }

    return this;
},
```

This is invoked in just a few places: when removing an element directly, or when updating an inner wrapper as a result of view navigation or other view swapping.

In most cases, the affected element has animation applied to it, which implies that the error is a side effect of an attempt to remove an element that has already been animated out of scope. The solution, as hacky as it seems, is to get the layout of the parent container, suppress its animation, remove your element, then reapply animation, like this:

```
container.getLayout().setAnimation(false);
// item removal or view change here;
container.getLayout().setAnimation(true);
```

Comment: The .setAnimation(false) then back to true worked for me. I was seeing this error a lot when popping a view inside of a handleNavBack method on a NavigationView I was using.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when using a form field with name="id"